# HTML make child div expand beyond parent div (without width: 9999px)

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time with HTML/CSS now. I'd love to create some sort of a slider with images placed side by side with `hidden overflow` (so when you press "next" arrow it will "move" pictures to the left (hiding the left one and showing the one that was hidden).

The problem is I can't make my div to go beyond its parent thus I can't line up my images side by side.

It looks like this:

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div id="images">
    <div class="image_container">
      <img src="" alt="1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="image_container">
      <img src="" alt="2"/>
    </div>
    ...
    <div class="image_container">
      <img src="" alt="3"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where #slider should be at `95%` of `width` and preferably height based on content,
`#images` should have "no width" - it should be based on the content and `max-height`~, `.image_container` should have the `width` of the img - these should line up one next to another.

Any ideas how can I achieve that? I've been trying lots of things and none of them work.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Could you please tell us you have tried (e.g - the css you have tried), then it might be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `display` property of the child elements to `inline-block` and the `white-space` property of the parent to `nowrap`.

```css
#parent{
  background:#000;
  height:100px;
  padding:5px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:200px;
}
#parent>div{
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#parent>div:nth-child(odd){background:#f00;}
#parent>div:nth-child(even){background:#0f0;}
```

```html
<div id="parent"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

Comment: You are my hero @Shaggy ;) It does work indeed, I did try it with same-sized images so far, but I believe I can deal with any further formatting to make it appear right. I did try that, but I missed nowrap on white-spaces. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :) If you feel this has satisfactorily answered your question, please consider accepting it.